# how to fetch data between two dates(From Date, To Date) tables in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Each date as one table in my database.In all Tables data is same but table is different. I want to search one column (this column is common for all tables).I passed dates like `2015-01-01` as `from date` and `2015-05-31` as `to Date`

I wrote the query like this but this is not working for me.

```
select MsgId, UserId, Priority, MsgStatus, 

FROM abc.`2015-05-04` as p1,abc.`2015-05-14` as p2 
WHERE  Id="cfcbc375-372e-4586-bc23-9e94e6eb2c16"
```

Comment: the table names are dates?

Comment: Is this table name abc.`2015-05-04` , abc.`2015-05-14` ?

Comment: God, that's the worst idea I have seen. You should simply create a column on your main table with the dates, instead of making a table for each day since the columns are the same in every table. It would make it easier to gather the information between dates.

Comment: If you will excuse me saying, I think your problem is a bad database design.

Comment: First time i see dates on a table name.

Comment: i also see it's first time. why this type of requirements are needed ? you can simply add a date column in your table and assign date to all data when its created.

Comment: table names are dates

Comment: @rao, you really need the table names to be dates?

Comment: you need to create one return type method which will return your starting date to end date(means table name). and call your query method inside the iterate date...

Comment: select * from tbl_node where mydate between '2014-02-02' and '2014-02-06';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve with append functionality Like this, Here we are taking from date to till date and after that converting date type to string format. now calling sql query till last date then use append functionality like `finalQuery = finalQuery + " " + " union all " + " " + query1;` Hope You will get data from start date to end date. :)

```
finalQuery = "SELECT  TransDate FROM `" + str_date + "` WHERE `Id`='" + Id 

for(int i=1;i<dates.size();i++){
   Date lDate =(Date)dates.get(i);
   ds = formatter.format(lDate);    


  for(int i=0;i<s;i++) {
      query1 = "SELECT  TransDate FROM `" + ds + "` WHERE `Id`='" + Id + "'";         
  }
  finalQuery = finalQuery + " " + " union all " + " " + query1;
}
```

Comment: yup now i'm getting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to search for a date use to_date

```
and >= to_date('22-12-2015','dd-mon-yyyy')
and <= to_date('21-01-2016','dd-mon-yyyy')
```

this would look for all instances where the date was between 22nd December and 21st January inclusive.

This is assuming that OP is misunderstanding the FROM part of an SQL statement, the dates should be in the WHERE/AND clauses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL

```
select MsgId, UserId, Priority, MsgStatus, 
       DestinationNumber, OrginatorName, MsgSubmitID,
       MsgStatusMsg, TransDate, ClientMsgId 
FROM abc.`2015-05-04` as p1
WHERE  Id="cfcbc375-372e-4586-bc23-9e94e6eb2c16"

UNION ALL

select MsgId, UserId, Priority, MsgStatus, 
       DestinationNumber, OrginatorName, MsgSubmitID,
       MsgStatusMsg, TransDate, ClientMsgId 
FROM abc.`2015-05-14` as p2 
WHERE  Id="cfcbc375-372e-4586-bc23-9e94e6eb2c16"
```

you should use union all for all table between `2015-05-04` and abc.`2015-05-14` like `2015-05-04`, `2015-05-05`, `2015-05-06` and so on

Answer (score 0):

I see. You have one table for each date, every table contains the same columns.

That's not how you design tables, it's bad programming.

You must create a new column in one table and add the dates into this column.

Then you can use it as:

```
select MsgId, UserId, Priority, MsgStatus, 
       DestinationNumber, OrginatorName, MsgSubmitID,
       MsgStatusMsg, TransDate, ClientMsgId 
FROM abc.`table`
WHERE  Id="cfcbc375-372e-4586-bc23-9e94e6eb2c16" AND
Date BETWEEN 'date1' and 'date2'
```

See [Between operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

Comment: table name as date yar(Daily Dates like 2015-12-22,2015-12-23,2015-22-24)